# Loss to compare true labels to distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, loss-functions

Say I have an input tensor like this:

```
# images = (?, 28, 28, 1)  # MNIST images
```

where the last dimension (the `1`) is a pixel value (grayscale, so they're numbers on [0-255] for 256 total possibilties).

And, accordingly the last layer of the neural network outputs something like this:

```
# logits = (?, 28, 28, 256)
```

where the last dimension (`256`) contains the "probability" (log odds/logit)
for each color (so a number at index 256 would be the logit of white (255) being
the correct color for that pixel).

How can I write a loss function in that compares the distrubution
the model predicts (`logits`) to the *single* correct value in `images`?

High-level intuitions are perfectly fine (i.e., code not needed).

---

#### Optional Details.

Right now, essentially, I'm forming a 2D `[BatchHeightWidthChannel, Distribution (256 cols)]` tensor, and checking against a 1D tensor (`images` flattened). Sadly, the network always says that index zero (black) is the most probable value at test time.

```
import tensorflow as tf

images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 28, 28, 1])
# ...network goes here ...
logits = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 28, 28, 256])

# Softmax Cross Entropy.
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits=tf.reshape(logits, (-1, 256)),  # [BatchHeightWidthChannel, Distribution]
    labels=tf.to_int32(tf.reshape(images, shape=(-1,))  # [TruePixelValues]
))
```

If that ^ 'looks right', that's helpful too (suggests the problem is elsewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are training some sort of auto-encoder, feeding it an image and checking if the reconstructed version of the image, encoded as 256 logits, is similar.

The naive thing to do would be simply encoding the image using [1-hot encoding](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f), that means converting the image from int array of shape `(28,28,1)` to boolean array of shape `(28,28,256)`, and then use this (possibly flattened) with cross entropy loss.

However, this approach has an obvious downside that it penalizes the network by the same amount whenever the pixel prediction is wrong, no matter *how much wrong* it is. E.g., if an original pixel is black (value 0) and gets predicted as white (value 255), it is penalized just as much as if it was predicted as nearly black (value 1) - it is still a different class.

Possibly much better way is simply changing the network to output a single number (i.e. the grayscale intensity) and use mean squared error.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I'm actually trying to implement a PixelCNN (see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05328.pdf)). The paper states that we want it to return a tensor of this form (in order to force it to build up a PMF for each pixel, I think...).

Comment: There is an [implementation on git](https://github.com/anantzoid/Conditional-PixelCNN-decoder), you can use it as a reference. Btw, when linking to arxiv papers, link to the abstract instead of the pdf. People will appreciate it more :)